# Lawn mower smoking-grey/white smoke

Tags: lawn-mower

I have a John Deere La145 Mower. It is 9 years old but only had 130 hrs. I changed air, oil, fuel filter today and began cleaning engine with engine degreaser. I also spilt some oil on frame when I took off oil filter. When I went to crank it up, I didn’t notice smoke at first but after running it in shop where I was working on it, I noticed smoke in the air. It appears it is coming from lower area of lawn mower. Smoke is not steady, sort of in puffs. When I cranked engine, it was running good. I checked air filter. No sign of oil. Everything looked fine. Oil level is not quite at full mark.

1. If I didn’t get all of the engine degreaser dried off, could that have caused smoke?
   I had sprayed it all in engine area.

Comment: If you are seeing “puffs” of smoke the engine is burning oil.  Surface oil might get hot enough to smoke, but your not going to be seeing “puffs”.

Comment: Ok. I am not sure if I described it best as puffs. It was producing a little smoke but it was not constant amount of smokes. It would be produce a little smoke, stop, and start again.

Comment: How does the engine run?  Does your fresh oil still look fresh on the dipstick?  Can you clean the oil off and it stops smoking?

Comment: Engine ran well. Sounded like normal. I didn't check oil after it smoked tonight. I was moving it from shop to another area where I stored it for the night. I ran it less than 3 or 4 minutes.

Comment: Oil left on an engine surface might smoke but won’t last and can be cleaned off.  If gas leaked into the oil the oil will turn white or grey and may be slightly bubbly or foamy.   White smoke is oil burning tho, gotta understand where it's coming from and how much.

Comment: I am going to take closer look tomorrow. You don't think degreaser residue that didnt get dry might have caused problem? I really couldn't see smoke coming out until I got in front of mower with engine run and looked toward bottom part of the front. It had to run a few minutes in the shop before I noticed there was smoke in the air. Was not thick smoke.

Comment: Don't think anyone will be able to answer further from where we sit and what we can see.

Comment: Late update- I checked oil level . Oil looked normal for brand new oil. Put 2 qts on oil change. Oil level was maybe quarter inch below the line to add oil. I was going to add oil to get to line before trying tomorrow. I did spill some oil pouring new oil so that might be why it is showing low.

Comment: If you turned the mower on its side it may be burning a little bit that got in the wrong place. It is also possible the choke has not fully opened in this short of time. I would run it until good and warm if still smoking check the choke. At 130 hours the motor should be tight, other things that can cause smoking bad fuel or putting mixed fuel in a 4 stroke, did you clean the carburator bowl/ float with today's methonal mix in the gas moisture can collect and cause poor performance.